# Fujitsu Siemens ServerView and SNMP Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I want to monitor the temperature of a couple of our servers, and since they're Fujitsu Siemens servers with ServerView installed I decided to check if SNMP was an option, and apparently it was.

However, I can't seem to figure out which OID to get, or even in which MIB to look for this information. As usual, the documentation seems to be pretty scarce or at least vague.

Concrete information on this case would be welcome, more than anything, but if you would have tips on how to look for the right OIDs in general that would probably help me on my way as well as I don't have a clue how to properly go about it right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What monitoring software are you using (Cacti, Munin, Nagios, Zabbix, other)? It may have built-in or community-contributed templates for your particular server.

Have a look on the manufacturer's website for MIBs relating to the hardware sensors (disk, CPU etc. are normally reported by the OS) - otherwise, `snmpwalk` a server and see if you can find anything that might correspond to temperature, keeping in mind the units may not be what you expect.

Comment: I'm using Icinga (the Nagios fork) but that obviously has nothing built in. I tried looking for the MIBs and I think I may have found them, but there's about 25 included in the package and so far I had no luck locating what I need. How do you start snmpwalking ? Don't you need an OID to start with?

Answer (score 2):

HI THERE!

Global state OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.231.2.10.2.11.2.1.0
It could return

1=OK, 2=Degrade,3=Error, 4= Fail, 5=unknown.

good luck!

Comment: could you tell me where you found this, and what else there is to be checked? "global state" doesnt mean a whole lot to me right now

Comment: http://forums.pandorafms.com/index.php?topic=2712.0 is one possible source

Answer (score 0):

You could try [monitoring with IPMI](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/IPMI_Sensor_Monitoring_Plugin). This should be available even on rather old servers from around 2010 or 2011 like Fujitsu Primergy with iRMC S2 or S3 that don't support SNMP (they can just send traps). Beware, IPMI can e.g. configure the server or power it on and off...